# Is there a debugger for gedit in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, debugging, ubuntu

I'm writing my code in gedit (in Ubuntu). Is there a C debugger I can use together with gedit?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [GNU debugger (GDB)](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) regardless of which text editor you're using. It's **the** standard debugging tool on Unix.

Comment: There is even [a  Text User Interface](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_21.html) built into most versions of GDB to make it work a little more like it's GUI-based cousins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Display_Debugger) which is a graphical front end for gdb.